# How to use React, jQuery and MaterializeCSS in the same project?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, materialize

I'm fairly new to Materialize, and I thought I could use it to develop a project with ReactJS. Unfortunately, looks like jQuery is not really liked by React. I tried to write some dummy code, which is just supposed to show a date input provided by Materialize:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'materialize-css';

class App extends Component {
   componentDidMount() {
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.datepicker').datepicker({
         disableWeekends: true
    });
  })
}
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="input-field">
        <input type="text" id="date" className="datepicker" />
        <label for="date">Choose a date you need me for...</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
 }
}
export default App;
```

This last snippet of code doesn't work, I get

```
TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...)(...).datepicker is not a function
```

I'm not a huge fan of jQuery, so I can drop it if I need to, but is there a way I can still use its methods (which I need access to for Materialize)?

Comment: Finding a React date picker component (there are many) would probably be much easier in the long run than trying to support jQuery in a React application.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is no longer a dependency for Materialize, so use the vanilla js initialisation instead of the jQuery initialisation:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
    var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems,{
       disableWeekends: true
    });

  });
```

> Because jQuery is no longer a dependency, all the methods are called
>   on the plugin instance. You can get the plugin instance like this:

```
var instance = M.Datepicker.getInstance(elem);
instance.open();
```

https://materializecss.com/pickers.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In React event listeners are supposed to be added in componentDidMount and removed in componentWillUnmount, right?